# How to put filter_values('filter_name') into a single quote in superset

Tags: apache-superset

How do one put {{ filter_values('filter_name')[0] }} into a single quote in superset?

For example,

```
WHERE upper('{{ filter_values('filter_name')[0] }}') == 'SOMETHING'
```

Basically, I want to treat the return value of {{ filter_values('filter_name')[0] }}  as a string. How to escape the single quote in filter_values('filter_name')?